# How to prevent symlink from creating within itself?

Tags: bash, symlink

Running the following command works as expected, creating a symlink to `src` from `include/bb`:

```
ln -sf ../src include/bb
```

However, calling the same command again will cause an additional symlink to `src` to be created in `include/bb` aka `src/src`.

What can I do to prevent it?

---

Edit:

Apparently this happens when `ln` is called twice, possibly the semicolon has nothing to do with it after all.

Here's a sequence of commands that will cause this to happen:

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir src
touch src/main.cpp
mkdir include
ln -sf ../src include/bb
ln -sf ../src include/bb
```

Comment: I don't think that does happen; `ln` doesn't even get to know about the semicolon. Can you [edit] in a brief script reproducing the issue you're having?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ln -s ../src include/bb
```

either creates a link named `include/bb` referring to `../src` (relative to its location), or it creates a file `include/bb/src` referring to `../src` (relative to its location). The latter is the case if `include/bb` exists and is a directory (actually or as a link to a directory).

Thus, when you've done the command once, there is now a link `include/bb` that points out the directory `src`, sibling to `include`. I.e., `include/bb` is now a directory. Therefore, when you do the command the subsequent time, a new link named `src` is added to that directory.

It has nothing to do with `;`.

You might have intended to use

```
ln -sTf ../src include/bb
```

instead, so as to (by `-T`) tell `ln` to treat any existing `include/bb` as a plain file (even though it's a link that refers to a directory), and (by `-f`) force that file to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
ln -s ../src include/bb
ln -s ../src include/bb
```

the first line makes a link `include/bb` to the directory `../src` (which is what you expected).

The second one finds that `include/bb` already exists. If it were a regular file, or a symlink to a regular file, that would be an error (unless you gave `-f` as well). Instead, it is a symlink to the *directory* `../src`, created in the previous step. When `ln`'s [target operand is a directory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html):

> the *ln* utility shall create a new [...] symbolic link, for each file specified by a *`source_file`* operand, at a destination path in the existing directory named by *`target_dir`*.

So this time around you're asking to create a link to `../src` inside `include/bb/`, which is (a link to) a directory. Those links are named by default according to their existing base names, which is `src` in this case. If you ran it a third time, you'd get an error because `../src/src` exists now.

---

You can avoid this by deleting the `include/bb` link beforehand every time with `rm include/bb`. The semicolon isn't involved in this.